# VF component email template to send list of opportunities against each owner. The templates loads the only last value of list

Tags: apex, email-template, visualforce-component, singleemailmessage

```
 //VF Component
    <apex:repeat value="{!oppUserList}" var="opp">
        <tr>
            <td>
                {!opp.Name}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>

    //Email template
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Review and Update Your Opportunities." recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <c:DraftOpportuniesEmailTemplate ></c:DraftOpportuniesEmailTemplate> 
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

`

```
public class DraftOpportunitesEmail{    
    public List<Opportunity> oppList{get;set;}
    public List<String> emailList{set;get;}
    public List<Opportunity> oppUserList{get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> oppUserList1{get;set;}
    public map<Id, List<Opportunity>> mapOwnerIdTolstOpp {get;set;}
    public string OwnerName {get;set;}
    public integer noOfOpp  {get;set;}
    Public DraftOpportunitesEmail(){        
        oppList=[Select Id,Owner.Email,Owner.Id, Owner.Name,Name , Account.Name,Status__c,createddate from Opportunity];        
        mapOwnerIdTolstOpp = new map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
        for(Opportunity objOpp: oppList)
        {
                if(!mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.containsKey(objOpp.OwnerId))
                {
                        mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.put(objOpp.OwnerId, new List<Opportunity>{objOpp});
                }
                else
                {
                        mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(objOpp.OwnerId).add(objOpp);
                }
        }
        system.debug('Map Opportunity Data : ' + mapOwnerIdTolstOpp);        
        for (Id key : mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.keySet()) {
                oppUserList = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key);
                system.debug('oppUserList' + oppUserList);
                OwnerName = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Name;
                string OwnerId = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Id;
                string OwnerEmail = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Email;
                noOfOpp = oppUserList.size();
              
        }   
        
    }
         Public void sendemail(){          
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        EmailTemplate  et = [select Id, Name from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'test'];
        for (Id key : mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.keySet()) {
                //oppUserList = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key);        
                this.oppUserList = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key);
                system.debug('Map User Data : ' + oppUserList);   
                List<String> sendTo = new List<String>(); 
                string OwnerName = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Name;
                integer noOfOpp = oppUserList.size();
                //String toAddresses = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Email;
                //sendTo.add(toAddresses);
                String OwnerId = userinfo.getUserId(); //mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Id;
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage ();
                string [] toaddress= New string[]{'xy@xy.com'};
                semail.setToAddresses(toaddress);
                semail.setTargetObjectId(OwnerId);
                semail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                semail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
                emails.add(semail);
                Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        }
       
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating the mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.keySet() to send emails and initializing

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage ();
```

inside the for loop, so for every value it would be reinitialized/remove the prev values and a fresh list is created.

Try taking the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage ();` line before the for loop and `Messaging.sendEmail(emails);` out of the loop like,

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage ();
    for (Id key : mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.keySet()) {
                this.oppUserList = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key);
                system.debug('Map User Data : ' + oppUserList);   
                List<String> sendTo = new List<String>(); 
                string OwnerName = mapOwnerIdTolstOpp.get(key)[0].Owner.Name;
                integer noOfOpp = oppUserList.size();
                String OwnerId = userinfo.getUserId(); 
                
                string [] toaddress= New string[]{'xy@xy.com'};
                semail.setToAddresses(toaddress);
                semail.setTargetObjectId(OwnerId);
                semail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                semail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
                emails.add(semail);
        }                
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```

Comment: am getting the email but issue is each user is getting the same list which is last record of the oppUserList

Comment: that is bcoz you are assigning value to toaddress, instead you have listofusers to whom mail has to be sent and a map that holds the lstOpp. Now you can iterate the list of users get the lstOpp using the map form the list of emails and out of the loop you can send them altogether. You might not need the second for loop in **DraftOpportunitesEmail** method as you are iterating the map formed in the prev for loop, you can get all those values in first loop